# AG-Grid create row data array using field name subsititutions

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

Using AG Grid we populate column defs array with column names returned by back end

Consider the array below , populated with data returned by the back end :

```
columnDefs: [
    { headerName: 'column_1', field: 'column_value_1' },
    { headerName: 'column_2', field: 'column_value_2' },
    { headerName: 'column_3', field: 'column_value_3' }
]
```

What TypeScript syntax could be used to implement the pseudo snippet below ? :

```
given rowData = []
given rowOfValues = [ row_value_1 , row_value_2 , row_value_3 ] // From Back End
given rowOfColumnNames= [ column_value_1 , column_value_2 , column_value_3 ] // From Back End

for index = 0 ; while index < rowOfValues.size ; index++

 add to rowData  ( rowOfColumnNames[index] : rowOfValues[index] )

return rowData
```

As per AG_Grid specification , the resulting rowData array wouuld be as follows :

```
rowData = [ { 
column_value_1: 'row_value_1', column_value_2 'row_value_2', column_value_3: row_value_3 } 
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ( let i = 0 ; i < rowOfValues ; i++ ) {

    object = {};

    object[rowOfColumnNames[i]] = rowOfValues[i];

    rowData.push(object);

}

return rowData;
```